# convert list of points to line or polygon

Tags: postgis, point, geometry-conversion

I have a list of Points in a PostGIS table. The rows can be grouped by a date

something like:

```
myTable
 id INT
 date DATE
 lat NUMBER
 lng NUMBER
 geom GEOMETRY(POINT)
```

now I need a table where all points of one day are collected in a new geometry (sorted by id)

```
targetTable
 id2 INT
 date DATE
 geom2 GEOMETRY(POLYGON)
```

how can I do this with PostGIS or GeoKettle, I cannot use any other client since this transformation has to be done in batch?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use ST_MakeLine function in postgis. info [here](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_MakeLine.html)...

> ST_MakeLine — Creates a Linestring from point or line geometries.

Example:

```
SELECT gps.gps_track, ST_MakeLine(gps.the_geom) As newgeom
    FROM gps_points As gps
    GROUP BY gps.gps_track;
```

i hope it helps you...

Comment: yes, ST_MakeLine works with the aggregated POINTs , thank You