# Adding multiple points to linestring in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, point, intersection, linestring

I have two linestring tables, both consisting of simple, 2-node line objects: one has the segments of exploded road centre-lines ('r_lines'), while the other has lines ('a_lines') from an addresspoint to the nearest point on the nearest centre-line segment, which in most cases is neither the start nor end node of that roadline segment.

Ultimately I need to have a table consisting entirely of (connected) 2-pt linestrings.

I haven't been able to figure out how to introduce the one endpoint of the a_lines into the r_lines to create new segments, and the problem seems to be that one r_line segment might be intersected by several a_lines. So [a previously described method for adding vertices to linestrings by breaking and re-merging](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/40622/how-to-add-vertices-to-existing-linestrings) can't be directly applied, unless I could do it iteratively (which I don't know how to do).

I have also tried dropping all the points into one table and then creating a new linestring with [the grouping method described here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26923/convert-list-of-points-to-line-or-polygon). This did create lines, but not the ones I was expecting, as they frequently seemed to double-back on each other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
select st_union(t1.wkb_geometry) as wkb_geometry into some_table from 
(
    select wkb_geometry from r_lines  union select wkb_geometry from a_lines
) t1
```

then viewing the result of some_table

The query above unions all your lines in r_lines and all your lines in a_lines into one result, then merges all of that together in one line and writes this to table some_table. If you need to then split this again, splitting at every intersection, we can explode this table using the query

```
select (st_dump(wkb_geometry)).geom as wkb_geometry into some_split_table from some_table
```

The output from above can be seen in some_split_table

Answer (score 2):

Use [`ST_Snap`](https://postgis.net/docs/manual-3.0/ST_Snap.html):

```
SELECT ST_AsText( ST_Snap('LINESTRING (0 0, 9 9, 20 20)', 
  'MULTIPOINT( (1 1.1), (12 11.9) )', 0.2));
```

```
                st_astext                
-----------------------------------------
 LINESTRING(0 0,1 1.1,9 9,12 11.9,20 20)
```